# SPA on Azure with SSL and URL Rewrites

Tags: azure, single-page-application

I have an SPA (Angular 9) that I have to host on Azure, using SSL with the ability to URL Rewrite crawlers to a Prerender VM. Until now I have achieved this using an App Service, but the S1 tier is a bit too much expensive considering the current traffic on the site.

I looked at hosting a static website on Blob Storage with Azure CDN as many answers recommend, **but** I would not be able to URL Rewrite to a VM (or other services) if a crawler is visiting my site, if I understood correctly.

I came to the conclusion that if I don't want to use an App Service I should use a VM, but I'm wondering if Azure offers something else I missed.

**Requirements**

- SSL
- URL Rewrite to a Prerender VM
- Cheaper than an App Service (at least for a low traffic website)

Thanks to everyone that will take the time to answer!

*More info on the app:*
It's currently served by a .Net Core Web API running in a S1 App Service. I'd like the API and the SPA to be separated because maintaining them would be easier and "responsibilities" would be decoupled (somewhat following the single responsibility principle of object oriented programming). I'm also moving the API to a VM because I'm required to add some functionalities leveraging a quite old ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I cannot read apparently.

Azure CDN docs has an explicit example of rewriting a url to a different destination:

[Azure CDN - URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#url-rewrite)

You want to look at the first sample scenario for URL Rewrites.

**Solution**

1. Add the prerender VM as an Endpoint in the CDN profile
2. Follow the **Sample Scenario 1** at [Azure CDN - URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#url-rewrite)